# The intent the app is asking for permission to send updates for is not found

Tags: actions-on-google

I sent my action to review and now it's approved. Not everything went well, because:

One of the functionalities (associated with notifications) doesn't work in the production-approved mode:

User: Sales (one of the suggestion chips)
App: Joy Shopping Advisor isn't responding at the moment. Try again soon.
Please make sure that a user can complete all core conversational flows listed in your registration information or recommended by your Action.

In the simulator we've got this kind of error:

expected_inputs[0].possible_intents[0].input_value_data: The intent the app is asking for permission to send updates for is not found..

I don't get it because we have turned on [User engagement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvJ5I.png). 
Next strange thing is that our error shows only on the production mode, not on the draft. On the draft everything looks and runs fine.

Thank you in advance,

Cheers,

Tomas

Comment: Have you refreshed the snapshot version that you're testing in the simulator?

Comment: Thanks for response. In the simulator we are testing our draft version. The same one that we deployed

Comment: The one thing that we sometimes make mistake on is to forget to refresh the test version to the latest draft. That should work. And if it doesn't, then I'm out of ideas :-/

Comment: We noticed that the push notifiactions works until it reviewed, even if the action is not accepted. After that we got this error.

We recently submit action to review again, now it's accepted and still error exist in production, not on the draft mode.

Comment: Having the same issue I have noticed that unselecting and selecting (a couple of times) the implicit intent related with push notifications at Dialogflow->Inplicit invocation and refreshing also the  Actions on Goole console-> actions the issue is solved. I have no clues to explain that behavior.